# Element's width changes every click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the width of an image and then make a div's width the same.

HTML

```
<!-- Thumbnail -->
<div class="work-img">
    <img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" target="15" src="images/15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.work-img img').click(function(){  // On thumbnail click
    $('.modal-body').find('img').attr({ // Find image tag and add attribute 
        src: "images/" + $(this).attr('target')+ "-1.jpg" // Add large image source according to image dynamically
    });
});
// Now the large image will be shown in the modal and I want to give the modal-dialog a width according to image width. For that I use this.
$("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () { // On modal show
    $('.modal-dialog').css({ // Add width using css to .modal-dialog
        width: $(this).find('.modal-body').find('img').width(), // Get the width of image, that was loaded dynamically
        'max-width': '80%' // max-width of the modal will be 80% of the screen
    });
    $('.modal-body').find('img').css('max-width', '100%'); // Add 100% width to loaded image so it remains in the modal-body
});
```

after this I get the width of the image but on every click it is decreasing the width by like 10%. What's the problem in my code?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: @TasosK. here you go I added the HTML too

Comment: Try width `auto` for your modal

Comment: @PawanNogariya I already done with width :auto but it fixes to 568px the default width of bootstrap modal and I want to add dynamically width according to large image

Comment: @QararUlHassan would a CSS approach would work for you?

Comment: @TasosK.I want to increase the width of bootstrap-modal if screen size is more then 768px if it helps me then its ok like I already have the screen detect JQuery

     if ($(window).width() > 768) {
  $("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () { 
      $('.modal-dialog').css({
       width: $(this).find('.modal-body').find('img').width(),
       'max-width': '80%'
        });
     $('.modal-body').find('img').css('max-width', '100%');
  });
 }

Comment: I went this far http://www.bootply.com/HIofOi6Gxq, but if you click left or right of the image, the modal wont close.

Comment: @TasosK. thanks for your effort but my problem is if I have a picture width 500px other is 400px and 3rd one is different then how I can resize the modal-body according to that picture.

Comment: It works for any size, so I believe it would suit you.